# Очистка таблиц MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Имеется БД сайта на Битриксе на хостинге, сильно раздулась одна из таблиц,  более 1 000 000 записей. Необходимо удалить все записи, кроме созданных за последнюю неделю.
Какие имеются варианты? Желательно посредством PHP, чтобы подключить на cron.

Comment: *Желательно посредством PHP, чтобы подключить на cron.* Совершенно нежелательно. Более того - весьма глупо привлекать два дополнительных посторонних инструмента, когда есть штатные, идеально приспособленные для таких задач. Удаление выполняется непосредственно на сервере одним несложным запросом, регулярное выполнение этого запроса организуется штатным планировщиком MySQL.

Comment: Можно поподробнее?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE EVENT delete_from_tablename_older_1week
ON SHEDULE 
    EVERY 1 DAY
    STARTS '2019-08-22'
DO
    DELETE 
    FROM tablename 
    WHERE creation_date < CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 WEEK;
```

Ну и не забыть включить планировщик - как в текущем сеансе:

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

так и в конфигурационном файле - для будущих рестартов. RTFM [Event Scheduler Configuration](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/events-configuration.html).